# How can I read the data from this json string?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json

```
[
   {
      "Intent":"what is manufacturer name?",
      "Entity":"Name",
      "Response":"Test",
      "Status":"0",
      "Created_Date":"2017-04-04T00:00:00",
      "Response_Count":0,
      "Response_Count_string":0
   },
   {
      "Intent":"hi",
      "Entity":"hi",
      "Response":"hiiii",
      "Status":"0",
      "Created_Date":"2017-03-28T10:22:00",
      "Response_Count":0,
      "Response_Count_string":0
   },
   {
      "Intent":"how are you?",
      "Entity":"are you fine",
      "Response":"good!cool",
      "Status":"1",
      "Created_Date":"2017-03-28T10:22:38",
      "Response_Count":0,
      "Response_Count_string":0
   }
]
```

Comment: Could you please give a little more insight into your question? What are you asking her? Where do you need to format the JSON data? Where do you want to read JSON data? What code have you already written?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to read this data in JavaScript or in C#?

Comment: If this is question wants a JavaScript answer it is a duplicate and should be marked as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: @tanmay Not really, assuming his json is stored as a variable from a response, and isn't actually plaintext with all those nasty looking escape characters. Why would it be hardcoded?

Comment: @divya why unaccept the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways to read the data from **JSON String :**

**1. Using Javascript**

```js
var jsonStr = "[{\"Intent\":\"what is manufacturer name?\",\"Entity\":\"Name\",\"Response\":\"Test\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-04-04T00:00:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"hi\",\"Entity\":\"hi\",\"Response\":\"hiiii\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"how are you?\",\"Entity\":\"are you fine\",\"Response\":\"good!cool\",\"Status\":\"1\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:38\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0}]";

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for (var i in jsonObj) {
  console.log(jsonObj[i].Intent);
}
```

**2. Using AngularJS**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    var jsonStr = "[{\"Intent\":\"what is manufacturer name?\",\"Entity\":\"Name\",\"Response\":\"Test\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-04-04T00:00:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"hi\",\"Entity\":\"hi\",\"Response\":\"hiiii\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"how are you?\",\"Entity\":\"are you fine\",\"Response\":\"good!cool\",\"Status\":\"1\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:38\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0}]";

    $scope.jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in jsonObj">
    {{item.Intent}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `data` is a stringified JSON. You should be able to just `JSON.parse` it.

Like this:

```js
var data = "[{\"Intent\":\"what is manufacturer name?\",\"Entity\":\"Name\",\"Response\":\"Test\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-04-04T00:00:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"hi\",\"Entity\":\"hi\",\"Response\":\"hiiii\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"how are you?\",\"Entity\":\"are you fine\",\"Response\":\"good!cool\",\"Status\":\"1\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:38\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0}]"

var jsondata = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(jsondata[0].Intent)
console.log(jsondata[1].Intent)
console.log(jsondata[2].Intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 
<p id="demo"> </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "[{\"Intent\":\"what is manufacturer name?\",\"Entity\":\"Name\",\"Response\":\"Test\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-04-04T00:00:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"hi\",\"Entity\":\"hi\",\"Response\":\"hiiii\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"how are you?\",\"Entity\":\"are you fine\",\"Response\":\"good!cool\",\"Status\":\"1\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:38\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0}]"; 
    var res = str.replace("\'", "");
    res=  JSON.parse(res)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0].Intent;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like

```
var resultStr = "[{\"Intent\":\"what is manufacturer name?\",\"Entity\":\"Name\",\"Response\":\"Test\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-04-04T00:00:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"hi\",\"Entity\":\"hi\",\"Response\":\"hiiii\",\"Status\":\"0\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:00\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0},{\"Intent\":\"how are you?\",\"Entity\":\"are you fine\",\"Response\":\"good!cool\",\"Status\":\"1\",\"Created_Date\":\"2017-03-28T10:22:38\",\"Response_Count\":0,\"Response_Count_string\":0}]";
   result = JSON.parse(resultStr);
       var data = result[0].Intent;
```